How to scale the material image based on user value?
I have a T-Shirt 3D Object model, and I have loaded that using SCNScene Kit. I need to change that model submesh material image size based on the user input value.
func AddNode(scene:SCNScene, viewerSetup: Insert3DViewer, modelSetup: Insert3DModel) -> SCNNode  {
    
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forAuxiliaryExecutable: modelSetup.mesh) else {
    fatalError("Failed to find model file.")
}

let asset = MDLAsset(url: url)
guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh else {
    fatalError("Failed to get mesh from asset.")
}

// Create a material from the texture
let scatteringFunction = MDLScatteringFunction()
let material = MDLMaterial(name: "baseMaterial", scatteringFunction: scatteringFunction)

let meshUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelSetup.material, withExtension: "")
material.setProperty(MDLMaterialProperty(name: modelSetup.material, semantic: .baseColor, url: meshUrl))

for  submesh in object.submeshes!  {
    if let submesh = submesh as? MDLSubmesh {
        submesh.material = material
    }
}

// Wrap the ModelIO object in a SceneKit object
return SCNNode(mdlObject: object) }

I have used one striped image as material, I need to increase/Decrease the Strip width based on user Scaling input.


You can use wrapS & wrapT on the material, so scale it for your needs. I just dont have an example, but it's pretty straight forward. Let me know if you need more help

You can set wrapS and wrapT to Repeat and set the transform scale.
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = "image.jpg"
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(4, 4, 1), SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0))
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat


looks pretty good - keep in mind: you will need to do this on each materiel property like "roughness", "metalness", "ambient occlusion" and "normal" (and probably more - depending on your material specific properties)
